# How do I get the counter clockwise value using the modulo operator?

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Let's say we have a 24 hour clock where all time is represented in minutes. That gives us 24 * 60 possible time points from 0 hours to 24 hours. The clockwise distance between two time points T1, T2 is simply |T1 - T2| since the time is represented in minutes.

Now, how do I obtain the counter clockwise distance between T1 and T2 ? Would I do something like

(-|T1 - T2|) % 1440?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you considered:
24 * 60 - |T1 - T2|

Comment: the counter difference is the compliment of the whole range.

Comment: Actually, clockwise (CW) and counterclockwise (CCW) are not clear...
If T2 > T1 : is that considered CW?  and vice versa?
if so, then it could be negative...

Comment: is 1440 == 0 for your question?

Comment: I think that if you define your question with more details, you'll come up with the answer yourself.